# Getting & setting values from xml in android

Tags: android, xml

I am new in android, I have a `MainActivity.java` in `src` and `activity_main.xml` in `layout`. If I create a button in `activity_main.xml`, then can I set or get the values of button properties in xml through `MainActivity.java` ?

how can change the property of PopupWindow like hieght,width through java

Comment: use your upvotes if anyone helped you. This is how the site works. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can modify the properties of your `View`s defined in a XML file.

For that, you have to put an ID in the `View` you want to modify in your `activity_main.xml`, for example:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    ... />
```

Then, in your `MainActivity` class, you can get this `Button` with the following method:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
```

Now, you can add every property you want on this View. You can for example set its text:

```
myButton.setText("Click me!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Get the button:

> > ```
> > Button button = findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
> > ```

Get properties (some examples):

> > ```
> > int x = button.getX;
> > int marginTop = ((ViewGroup.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams()).topMargin;
> > ```

Set porperties:

> > ```
> > button.setX = someValue;
> > ((ViewGroup.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams()).topMargin = someValue;
> > ```

Comment: if you have the view (with findViewbyId) you can use the setters and getters in all classes

Comment: I just want to add a method that is used to change any property like hieght, width ,or else 
like this , 
  public void setPopupWindowHieght(PopupWindow pwin,int h)
  {
  ((ViewGroup.LayoutParams)pwin.getLayoutparams()).hieght=h;
  }
but i have an error " The method getLayoutparams() is undefined for the type PopupWindow" 
Can u help me?

Comment: PopupWindow other methods becaus it doesn´t extend the View.class. Just check android developer documentations to explore which methods you can use with an class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. All the XML attributes of any view has an equivalent java method.

for example you can change the text in XML using

```
android:text="Hello World!"
```

similarly you can change the text **During runtime** using java code like this:

```
textView1.setText("Hello World!");
```

both will give the same result.

**[NOTE]** remember that code in XML is **predefined** at compile time but the java code takes effect at **runtime**. i.e only after you run the app in the device/emulator. So you can't see the changes made by java code in the UI editor itself. **Java code will only reflect during runtime.**

Answer (score 1):

In Xml file - you can set value for button as,

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_Save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Save"
        />
```

To get the button values in a Java file then can use like this,

```
Button btn;
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Save);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
String buttonText = btn.getText().toString();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button text is:" +buttonText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the properties defined in xml dynamically. But you cant write to those xml files (eg color, strings, dimen etc)

Example to set Button properties

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/seeLater"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_message"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/dialog_read_later"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="@dimen/settings_tile_heading_size" 
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Following xml files under res folder to define properties

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="White">#ffffff</color>  
</resources>
```

**dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="settings_tile_heading_size">13sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="dialog_read_later">LATER</string>
</resources>
```